# How to handle error in parameters of stored procedure in MYsql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addOrders`(
IN  V_DATA VARCHAR(10),
OUT v_result VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;
IF @errno = 1406 THEN
    SET v_result = "invalid information";
END IF;
END;
END
```

when i run this procedure (call era.addOrders('asdakjsdlkasjd;lajsdla;lskd;la', @v_result);
I got SQL error 'Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'V_DATA' at row 1   0.000 sec'.
But it is not caught by my exception handler.

Comment: Your code didn't even start executing. `'asdakjsdlkasjd;lajsdla;lskd;la'` cannot be stored in `VARCHAR(10)`.

Comment: This is not a compilation error. it generates at run time.is there any way i can throw this error to my exception handling block.

Comment: *This is not a compilation error.* Thee is no SP compilation in MySQL. *it generates at run time.* That's true that at runtime, but false that in SP. The error occures in CALL statement which tries to call this SP, which is out of this SP.